# Server Datasnap and client AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, delphi, datasnap

I created a DataSnap in delphi XE7 in the server side. I try to create a AngularJS application in the client side to consume the services of server side. But not found documentation about this, and my client application can't work fine. In the debug mode, the message "ReferenceError: TServerMethod1 is not defined".

The line erro is this:

```
this._proxy = new TServerMethod1(DSConnectionInfo);
```

The complete AngularJS code is this:

```
var module = angular.module('AngularIntro', []);
module.value('DSConnectionInfo', {host:'localhost',port:'8089'})

module.factory('DataSnap', function(DSConnectionInfo){
  if (!("_proxy" in this))
        this._proxy = new TServerMethod1(DSConnectionInfo);
      return this._proxy;
  })

module.controller('myController', function($scope, DataSnap){
    $scope.customers = DataSnap.GetCustomers(1).result;
  });
```

Please help!!!! And Tanks!!!!

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Where are you defining the `TServerMethod1` class?

Comment: No, I not defined TServerMethod1 and I dont know how to do this. I catch this example in the web. If I put the address "localhost:8089/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethod1/GetCustomer/1" its run fine, but directly in the web browser and not in the AngularJS